# Can anyone identify this bike please?

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

I bought this bike at a police auction and it is all aluminium and I was told it is a track bike.

The serial number under the frame is VISP120888 OR V1SP120889

On the crank it has  1R9CBA and R9FAA 16JUN09 and 170, and letters FSA.

Comment: Please add well-lit photos showing a side view from the right, and closer shots of the fork, head tube/badge, the seat tube cutout and anything else that looks unique.

Answer (score 1):

VISP appears to be a brand available on Amazon.  170 means the length of the crank arm in mm.  FSA is "Full Speed Ahead" they probably made some part of the transmission, so likely the cranks and maybe the front chainrings/bottom bracket. 16 June 2009 could be the manufacturing date for the cranks, which sound newer than the rest of the bike.

120889 sounds like a date, 12 August 1989 or 8 December 1989 (yay for ambiguous foreign date formats)   but 1989 sounds slightly early for an aluminium bike.

A proper track bike would have no brakes, and probably just one gear in single speed.  It would also have the rear wheel tucked in super-close to the seat pole.

More info please.